# How to find the framework/download/install instructions of a dependency if all you have is a using directive? C# project

Tags: c#, dependencies

I want to use a github C# project, but there are 2 missing namespaces/dependencies. Unfortunately the owner of the repo did not provide us with anything else than the name of these namespaces, no framework or other instructions.

https://github.com/platatat/SnapCall

The two Dependencies are:

```
using Combinatronics;
```

and

```
using ProtoBuf;
```

Trying to install these through the Terminal using the following command:

```
dotnet add package Combinatronics --version 1.0.3.2
```

Gives the following error:

```
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Combinatronics' into project 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\SnapCall\SnapCall.csproj'.
error: Error while adding package 'Combinatronics' to project 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\SnapCall\SnapCall.csproj'. The project does not support adding package references through the add package command.
```

However, even without the error, how does the Terminal even know what package im trying to install? Just from the name and version?

Bear with me please I am pretty new to C# projects and I want to learn.

Any help/input is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Googling "protobuf" yields Protocol Buffers, which is what I would expect.

Comment: This project is for .NET Framework v4.5.2. Try adding packages via IDE UI.

Comment: _Unfortunately the owner of the repo did not provide us with anything else than the name of these namespaces, no framework or other instructions_: [Snapcall packages.config file](https://github.com/platatat/SnapCall/blob/master/packages.config). It's not clear what version of _.NET_ you're using, but _.NET_ uses SDK style packages. You may consider reading about [PackageReference vs Packages.config](https://www.google.com/search?q=packagereference+vs+packages.config)

Comment: As someone else commented, the [SnapCall .csproj file](https://github.com/platatat/SnapCall/blob/master/SnapCall.csproj) shows `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.  It's necessary to understand the differences between _.NET_ and _.NET Framework_.

Answer (score 2):

This solution was build for .NET Framework 4.5.2. For packages you can look into [packages.config](https://github.com/platatat/SnapCall/blob/master/packages.config) file:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Combinatorics" version="1.0.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="protobuf-net" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

And I doubt that this solution supports adding packages via `dotnet` CLI (which is usually used for .NET (Core) projects), so try installing packages via IDE UI.

I highly recommend trying to upgrade the solution because .NET 4.5.2 is out of support and very dated (maybe the easies option would be to create a new one and move files there).

Comment: I have no idea how to do any of these things unfortunately. I did however find the packages.config file before, thats how I knew the version was 1.0.3.2. But again, I dont have enough knowledge at the moment for any of this information to be useful...

Comment: Based on quick scan - the project does not seem to use anything .NET Framework specific. Create new .NET (Core) project and move files there.

Comment: Maybe you'll even find somebody to help you with that by creating a Fork on GH? (Given the license allows for that)